# Generate insert statements from database using Eclipse/STS

Tags: sql, eclipse, sql-insert, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

We have an established database with many records. We are moving to a new environment and so need to ship over the data. We would like to be able to generate a ddl script that will create our tables, then populate them with the existing data.

We use Springsource tool suite v2.9.2 as our IDE, with the Database Development view as our only db viewer. (unable to get more software)

Is there an option that we can't find to generate a ddl and the insert statements to go with it? Will we have to rely on our DBA team to do this behind the scenes and not mess it up...

Comment: I don't know much about this area, but you can look at the Data Tools Project: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Data_Tools_Platform_Project

Answer (score 1):

I've created a plugin that may help at https://github.com/kirenpillay/sqlinsert. It works only with Luna for the moment.

There's also the SQL Insert Script generator which you can get from Eclipse marketplace.